# printer driver auto colour setting

Tags: printer, print-drivers

I've read the documentation for my Brother HL-8250 colour laser printer with regard to settings.

There is an "Auto colour" setting which detects if  the document contains mono/colour and "if colour is detected anywhere in the document it will print the whole document using all of the colours...".

It is not explicitly clear whether the printer than uses composite black, or from the black toner for text/black stuff. My interpretation is that it is composite & therefore wasteful.  Can anyone confirm this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most printers will print greyscale using all cartridges rather than just black. Most of the toner will be black, but small amounts of colour will be used. This is done to get a larger range of greys than is possible using black only.

On the other hand, black items like text and lines will always be printed using black toner only, regardless of the colour setting. If the printer printed composite black, the print would suffer from 2 problems. First the black would not be black. Instead you'd get some dark colour, typically purple or brown. This is because the inks never have the theoretical cyan/magenta/yellow colours that add to a true black.

The second problem is that you would then print black as 300% coverage. In a laser that would almost certainly not fuse properly, and toner would flake off the paper. In an inkjet it would soak the ink right through the paper.

Lastly, aligning all 4 colours accurately is almost impossible so, if your printer used colour toner in black text, you would see colour around the edges of the characters. This is not desirable.

Comment: Thanks, how then to interpret the 'colour' setting?  The manual states:" Whether the document contains colour or monochrome, your machine will print the document using all the colours" . That sounds like composite black to me?

Comment: In the "colour" setting, colour and greyscale will be printed with all toners. Hence a monochrome image will use some colour. Black will be printed with black toner only. No printer uses composite black, for the reasons I gave. I have also added another reason in my answer,